# Command line tool for scraping flight prices?

Tags: gratis, python, github

I want to have a free-to-use code (ideally from **github**, ideally in **python**) to scrape flight prices automatically for various connections, dates, times, airlines etc. which I can run at different *times*, ideally using different *User Agent Strings* (so the web page thinks its from a mozilla browser or chrome browser etc) etc., in order to really find the cheapest international flight.

On github I found various projects like [expedia.py](https://gist.github.com/scrapehero/bc34513e2ea72dc0890ad47fbd8a1a4f), [Flight Price prediction](https://github.com/amitjoshi9627/Flight_Price_prediction), [Airfare Tracker](https://github.com/landrieu/AirfareTracker) and [flight scraper](https://github.com/antodippo/flight-scraper), but these projects seem to be a couple of years old and I could not find any up-to-date project at least on github.

So has someone a software recommendation for an up-to-date flight scraping code/tool/application?

#### Must have

- Free
- For International flights (departure and return date)
- Command line tool for automated use

#### Nice to have

- github project
- python

#### Not important

- Currency can be any currency

Comment: Curious if you found something interesting